# ASP - Validation RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have two System.Web.UI.WebControls **radioButton** --> "Yes" and "No".

- When I checked RButton "Yes" -> RButton "No" is Disable.
- When I unchecked RButton "Yes" -> RButton "No" is Enable.

---

- When I checked RButton "No" -> RButton "Yes" is Disable.
- When I unchecked RButton "No" -> RButton "Yes" is Enable.

[image]

Need BACK END LOGIC Like this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
    }
```

Thank you previously!

Comment: <table>
<tr><td>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" value="1a" />Option1 
    <input name="group1" type="radio" value="1b" />Option2 
</td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use 2 different Radio Buttons ..?? you can use `RadioButtonList`

[Here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/radiobuttonlist-example-how-to-use.html) is link